# Scanning known locations on a plane

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Imagine a plane with a number of points at known locations. Most are clustered close together, but some are outliers, and there are large areas where there are no points at all. I have multiple clients who can view the plane through rectangular viewports. Each client's viewport may be of different dimensions, and can be moved instantly to any location on the plane. The clients do not know the locations of the points; only the server does. When a client connects, it will communicate the size of its viewport to the server, and the server should respond with a location where one or more points will be visible to that client's viewport. The client visits that location, collects data from visiting those points, sends that data back to the server, then requests the next location to visit. This continues until all points have been visited by at least one client.

I need an efficient algorithm that will choose the locations to visit. An ideal solution will minimize the number of locations that clients need to visit by including as many unvisited points as possible within a viewport location, minimizing duplicate visits on points, and not visiting locations with no unvisited points. Can you recommend an algorithm?

Comment: This is similar to [the set covering problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), though you have the additional wrinkle that your sets are determined by choosing where to place a viewport and so getting the list of them possible sets is probably more expensive than you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, it's similar, but as you mentioned, figuring out all the possible sets is prohibitively expensive.... If I knew that all the viewports would be the same size, I'd just lay a grid over the plane and have the clients visit all graticules which contain any points, which should be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this:

```
   1) generate a Dalauney triangulation for the points  
   2) sort the triangles by size    
   3) for each vertex in the largest triangle:  
       3a) locate a corner of the viewport at the vertex  
       3b) try each neighboring point on the longest diameter of the viewport
       3c) determine orientation which encloses the maximum number of points  
       3d) position viewport at that orientation
       3e) goto step (3b)  
   4) delete the visited points
   5) goto step (3)
```

Comment: Wow, lot of fun math in that one. I'll have to get back to you on that one. But one thing I realize I didn't make clear is the viewport cannot be rotated, only translated.

Comment: I'm not certain what is meant by "try each neighboring point on the longest diameter of the viewport". Could you elaborate?

Comment: lets say your viewport is a diamond with points ABCD, the long diameter of the diamond behing AC. You place A at each vertex of the largest triangle, then you try each neighboring point, X, to the triangle by rotating the viewport such that X is colinear with AC. You record the number of points inside the viewport at that orientation.

Comment: If the viewport cannot be rotated, then you do the same procedure, but you skip step 3b.